# How to select all columns including all inheritance columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So this is my entity:

```
public class Stock {
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

I have a lot of inheritance to this `Stock`:

```
public class StockA : Stock {
    public string Spec { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class StockB : Stock {
    public string Color { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class StockC : Stock {
    public string Variant { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class StockD : Stock {
    public string Type { get; set; }
    ....
}

.....
```

Let us say there are more than 10 inheritances. How can I get all columns from `Stock` and its inheritances?

For example I need these columns:

```
ID
Qty
Spec
Color
Variant
Type
....
```

I tried to define a combined entity:

```
public class AllStock {
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public string Spec { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Variant { get; set; } 
    public string Type { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

I set it in my `DBContext`:

```
public DbSet<AllStock> AllStocks { get; set; }
```

But when I query it:

```
var x = await db.AllStocks.ToList();
```

It returns empty list. I suppose this `AllStock` entity is separated from the other entity.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have data in db for AllStocks Entity? Have you register your context in Startup file? What result you expect kindly brief about with example.
There is lot's of confusion with your question.
Does Stock is local model? If yes then you can use Automapper to map your data with local model.

Comment: It is Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `Select`:

```cs
var result = await db.Stocks
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.ID,
        x.Qty,

        Spec    = x is StockA ? ((StockA)x).Spec    : null,
        Color   = x is StockB ? ((StockB)x).Color   : null,
        Variant = x is StockC ? ((StockC)x).Variant : null,
        Type    = x is StockD ? ((StockD)x).Type    : null
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This gives me empty result

Comment: Strange why. Looks like another EF bug. Anyway, next time describe which hierarchy storage do you use.

Comment: Remove `AllStocks` and test my approach again. Or better post generated SQL.

Comment: Actually your answer is right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this with `FromSqlRaw`.

First assign the `DbSet`:

```
public DbSet<StockVM> AllStocks { get; set; }
```

then set the model builder with `HasNoKey`:

```
mb.Entity<StockVM>().HasNoKey();
```

then this is the query:

```
return db.AllStocks.FromSqlRaw(@"
    SELECT" +
    GetSelect() +
    @" FROM Stocks
        INNER JOIN Colors ON Stocks.ColorId = Colors.ID
        INNER JOIN Units ON Stocks.UnitId = Units.ID
        INNER JOIN Items ON Stocks.ItemId = Items.ID
        INNER JOIN ItemTypes ON Stocks.ItemTypeId = ItemTypes.ID
    ");
```

Also I have to create an entity with all of the properties:

```
public class StockVM{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public string Spec { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Variant { get; set; } 
    public string Type { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

---

### IMPORTANT

Be careful with the migration, make sure you delete the `AllStock` from the `Up()`. Or it will try to create a new column.